# AngulaJs Not Getting Scope Variable to Specific Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new one with angularJs so i saw many post how to make controller etc but in every controller we pass scope to get particular values which is defined in specific view which handles controller.i am sending my code that why i don't getting my views value using $scope when i am debuging so and want to get values $scope.LoginName 
Error:- Undefined can'nt read property.

it's accessing $scope.loggedIn but not accessing login view values .

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="LoginController">

    <div ng-switch="loggedIn">
      <div ng-switch-when="false">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><b>Consumely</b></a>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-ng-controller ="inventoryNavController">
                        <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/Login')}"><a href="#/Login">Login</a></li>
                        <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/SignUp')}"><a href="#/SignUp">SignUp</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-view class="viewStyle"></div>
      </div>

      <div ng-switch-when="true">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><b>Consumely</b></a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class=""><a ng-click='logout()' >Log Out</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Send Invite</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/Stores')}"><a href="#/Stores">Stores</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-view class="viewStyle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Controllers -->

    <!-- login Controller -->
    <script src="app/controllers/loginController.js"></script>

    <!-- services -->

    <!-- login service -->
    <script src="app/services/loginService.js"></script>

  </body>
```

LoginView.html

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login-Name" class="col-lg-3 form-label">User Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-Name" ng-model="LoginName" name="login-Name" placeholder="User Name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login-Password" class="col-lg-3 form-label">Password:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-Password" ng-model="LoginPass" name="login-Password" placeholder="Password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

loginController.js

```
app.controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, loginService, $location) {

    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;

      $scope.login = function() {

          var user = {
              "username" : $scope.LoginName,
              "password" : $scope.LoginPass
          }
      }; 
});
```

Please kindly if any one know help me out.

Comment: It looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/mPyU2/. Please clean up your code formatting and trim down the example. Also try to narrow down your error to a specific line which can be done via `console.log()`.

Comment: @DanKanze Thanx Problem solved by both pattern as u told me by predefining or like as u show  in fiddle by both.